# How connecting postgresql remotelly?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to set up postgesql server and connect to server as client but I want do this for locally connected together.How can I do this ?(prefer on windows);
I mean that I want in university assign one computr as server that operating system is windows and there is a computers that I want connecting them to server and get datas from servers database.

Comment: This question is unclear *and* too broad. Read the documentation, try it, read the gazillion SO questions that deal with your specific connection problem, and then ask again. A specific question can elicit a useful answer.

Comment: You can do this with pgAdmin, Navicat, SQLyog or EMS Database Manager for PostgreSQL. Or even programmatically from PHP with `pg_connect()` function.

Comment: can you explain more about or suggest a documentation that have done this job.